# Maximum Likelihood Efficiency

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information, efficiency

It is a well-known fact that ML estimates are not efficient in the class of consistent, asymptotically normal estimates due to the existence of superefficient estimates. The right way to put it is that they are efficient in the class of extremum estimates. One of my professors told me that "in the class of extremum estimates" can be interchanged with "for which Fisher information is defined" (so we can see whether the estimator achieves Cramer-Rao lower bound), implying that Fisher information is not defined for superefficient estimates. Is this correct?